# Is there a way to change the behavior of set to automatically trim the string properties on assignment in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a way to automatically trim the property value of the strings on assignment. I am aware that i can use something like this:

```
private string _firstName;
public string firstName 
{ 
    get { return _firstName; } 
    set { _firstName = value.Trim(); }
}
```

but I have so many classes with so many string properties and doing it like so does not seem so feasible. I was wondering if there is a way to perhaps change the behavior of the setter to always set it to the string.trim() instead.

Comment: I doubt that it's possible

Comment: "doing it like so does not seem so feasible" - in what way? (There's no way of doing this in a more global way unless you start looking into source generators. I would personally be wary of doing this universally anyway...)

Comment: I'd tackle the problem in the opposite direction - why are you so often in your code base ending up with strings with extraneous leading/trailing whitespace? Can you not cure that problem instead?

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate all the comments.